# Getting All Of The Points In An Existing Curve?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I'm using ZedGraph and want to know how I can find the points that make up an entire curve.

```
foreach(var Curve in GraphPane.CurveList)
{
    foreach(var Point in Curve.???)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Point.X+" "+Point.Y); // <- I'm not sure if this is correct, but this is what I want
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the docs (http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_CurveList.htm), maybe try something like this:

```
foreach( var Curve in GraphPane.CurveList )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < Curve.Points.Count; i++ )
    {        
        var Pt = Curve.Points[i];
        Console.WriteLine(Pt.X+" "+Pt.Y);
    }
}
```